# Можно, ли используя неявный Intent (filter) открыть Intent в другом приложение?

Tags: java, android

Можно, ли неявным интентом открыть второе (не МайнАктивити) в другом приложении Андроид или использовать BroadcastReceiver как правило.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните вопрос. В текущем виде он не согласуется с приведенным вами решением.

Answer (score 1):

Это работает!

```
new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName(Package, Class));
```

но это немного не то что я ищу...

манифест примерно такой:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:label="SA"
       <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   </intent-filter>-->
```

Comment: подсмотрел ответ по сервисам, спасибо xkor